# How to unhide the unchecked warning when ClassTag is synthesised for a type with erased parameters?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

Pattern matching on type parameter `T` raises the unchecked warning

```
scala> def f[T](v: List[Any]): List[T] = v.collect { case x: T => x }
                                                             ^
       warning: abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
def f[T](v: List[Any]): List[T]
```

which one might try to resolve with `ClassTag`

```
scala> def f[T: scala.reflect.ClassTag](v: List[Any]): List[T] = v.collect { case x: T => x }
def f[T](v: List[Any])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): List[T]
```

which resolves the warning for simple class-based types

```
scala> f[String](List(42, "a"))
val res7: List[String] = List(a)
```

however now the unchecked warning becomes hidden even for types with parameterised types that have erased components at run-time

```
f[List[String]](List(List(42)))
val res9: List[List[String]] = List(List(42)) // oops!
```

How can we continue to raise the unchecked warning in the latter case?

Answer (score 5):

Scala 3 [replaces](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/type-test.html#typetest-and-classtag) `ClassTag` with `TypeTest`, or its shorthand `Typeable`, which does warn when we attempt to check more than just the class component of a type

```
scala> def f[T: scala.reflect.Typeable](v: List[Any]): List[T] = v.collect { case x: T => x }
def f[T](v: List[Any])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.Typeable[T]): List[T]

scala> f[String](List(42, "a"))
val res0: List[String] = List(a)

scala> f[List[String]](List(List(42)))
1 |f[List[String]](List(List(42)))
  |                               ^
  |               the type test for List[String] cannot be checked at runtime
val res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(42))
```

As [smarter](https://gitter.im/lampepfl/dotty?at=5fb7e5862a6c794bd8f8478e) puts it

> `TypeTag` doesn't exist anymore
>
> `ClassTag.unapply` for type tests is unsound and shouldn't be used
>
> instead we have `TypeTest` now: [lampepfl/dotty#7555](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/7555)